# "Ongoing therapy in order to get a better mental health is a good idea."

Tags: word-usage, word-request

> Ongoing therapy in order to get a better mental health is a good idea.

This sentence makes perfect sense to me, but looking at the definition it says "ongoing" is not a verb and is an adjective meaning "progressing", so am I misusing the word ongoing and is there a word that sounds similar that means what I mean to say?

Comment: The word **ongoing** is not wrong. You require an adjective here (ongoing, continuing, continual, extensive etc if you are referring to a lengthy process.  But your sentence is clumsy. We speak of **better mental health** NOT **a better mental health**.  And **to improve / enhance mental health** works better than **get**.

Comment: But I meant ongoing as a verb as in "taking therapy".

Comment: Then why not "taking therapy".  There is no standard verb "to ongo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Having/taking/going into** therapy in order to **improve/enhance/look after/maintain** mental health is a good idea.

The original sentence doesn't make much sense because you don't describe any ongoing therapy in particular, you make a statement. You are looking for a gerund phrase to start this sentence with.

> **Eating this cake** is easy.

> **Traveling** is a good way to expand your worldview.

> **Taking therapy** might be beneficial to your health.

Or you could simply go with

> Therapy is a good way to improve mental health.

Comment: Ah, so ongoing is not a verb?

Comment: @rikuwang no, it's an adjective originated from the phrasal verb "go on"

Comment: “Taking therapy” is awkward to me (US English). We “go to” therapy or “see” a therapist.